# Store pointers in Swift

Tags: string, swift, pointers

The initializer for my class `Field` receives an inout String.

```
class Field: NSObject {

   var placeHolder: String?
   var text: String?

   init(placeHolder : String, inout text: String) {
      self.placeHolder = placeHolder
      self.text = &text
   }

}
```

I want to be able to store the `text` variable pointer so I can change its value later. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I am confused actually, what are you trying to do.

Comment: I want to be able to change a String's value from other classes passing its pointer. For example: my view controller has the 'Name' string and I want to change it's value from the Field Class.

Comment: I suspect you may be better off using Key-Value Observing (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an `NSMutableString` instead of a Swift `String` comes to mind, as `NSMutableString` is a class, and thus passed by reference.

edit: try messing with the following in a playground.

```
import Foundation

class Field: NSObject {

    var placeHolder: String?
    var text: NSMutableString?

    init(placeHolder : String, text: NSMutableString) {
        self.placeHolder = placeHolder
        self.text = text
        super.init()
    }

    func mutateIt() {
        text?.appendString("mutated")
    }
}

var mutStr = NSMutableString(string: "Hello")
mutStr.appendString("Why")

var aField = Field(placeHolder: "", text: mutStr)
aField.mutateIt()

println(mutStr)
```

Comment: `inout` has already specified it will change the original text value?

Comment: Doesn't work with NSMutableString. And yes, inout passes the pointer.

Comment: That's why I said I got confused. The way you describe isn't it exactly the same what you want to do?

Comment: `inout` isn't needed if you change `text` in the Field class to `NSMutableString`.

Comment: It works if you append a string. But if you assign a different value, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MaddTheSane It isn't because it is passed _by_ reference but because it is a _reference type_. (I've made this same mistake.)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do would be very dangerous. How can you guarantee that your "string pointer" would be pointing at anything later? Consider this code:

```
func stringChanger(inout s : String) {
}
func f() {
    var s = "howdy"
    stringChanger(&s)
}
```

If `stringChanger` could *store* a pointer to `s` for use "later", all hell would break loose when it tried to set `s` "later" through that pointer, because the original `s`, the thing pointed to, is a temporary variable and won't exist "later" at all!

That is why Swift makes it hard to do: it's trying to protect you from yourself (and succeeding). Rethink your goal!

It would be better if you asked a question describing your ultimate *goal*, whatever it may be, rather than a question limited to a narrow *means* that are not in fact available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably check how to use **Protocol** instead. I did not see anyone using the `inout` keyword like this before. Usually, they use it in methods in order to modify the passed in parameter within the same scope instead of an initializer. Right now, you have crossed the class level and I am not sure about it. Also, readability will be improved if you use **Protocol**.

Comment: Not sure on how to achieve the same result with a **Protocol**

Comment: The purpose is to change your passed in `text` right? You can create a **Protocol** that have a method to change the text when something happen. Strongly suggest to download **Swift** book from Apple and explanation is great. If you want to be a good developer in iOS, you have to know **Protocol**.